# Vaadin window scrolling

Tags: vaadin7

I have  a vaadin window with a specific size When  the browser window is small, some fields aren't visible (probably because of the size of the window). We need to enable scrolling in these cases.So I try to add the content of my window in a panel but it doesn't work .Have you any idea please?

```
    setModal(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setClosable(false);
    Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
    VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
   content.addComponent.......
    content.setSizeFull();
    mainPanel.setContent(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that came to my mind, is to set both max-height and 100% height of the modal window, so that if the content has not enough space (due to browser window size) scrollbar will appear. Contrary, when browser window is big enough, max-height come into play and the modal window is centered and has predefined in ccs max-height.

Code sample that works in my app:

```
windowOpenButton.addClickListener(event -> {
    Window window = new Window();
    window.setWidth("100px");
    window.setHeight("100%");
    window.setModal(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setClosable(false);
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Button close = new Button("close");
    close.addClickListener(event1 -> window.close());
    VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout(new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), new Button(), close);
    content.setSizeFull();
    panel.setContent(content);
    window.setContent(panel);
    window.setStyleName("max_height");
    panel.setSizeUndefined();
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
});
```

css:

```
.max_height {
    max-height: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can just use **`setSizeFull()`** in your window to achieve that

so your code will be like :

```
setModal(true);
setResizable(false);
setClosable(false);
setSizeFull()
Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
content.addComponent.......
content.setSizeFull();
mainPanel.setContent(content);
```